# Get my id from SSRS report without user id function

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm connecting SSRS to SQL server using service id 'domain\xyz'. But when I open [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog], I see my user id 'abc'. How to find out my id on report. I'm trying to understand how user id 'abc' is stored in this [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLog] when am connecting using service id 'domain\xyz'.Is there a way, I can get display my id without using "user id" function as a paramter?

Comment: I have ssrs 2008 and ssrs 2016 instances.. and both of them show domain\username for me in the execution logs. but how can you get an the user id without using the user id function?

Comment: Have you tried using the Global `User!UserID` field in a textbox to see which it returns?

Comment: I tried that. I do not want to use that. Actually, my requirement is when a user queries data only their records should come. I have handle this using row level at DB side. How to do on SSRS side without using user!userID?